# I'm using 2" EPS below grade insulation for radiant floor heating, Do I need a poly vapor barrier on top?

Tags: insulation, floor, heat

In addition to 2" of EPS do I need a poly in a radiant floor heating system

Comment: Hello and welcome to DIY. Can you explain a bit more of what you are doing? Where is the EPS? Wall? Floor/inside/outside? How are you building up the framing and flooring? Also, please take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: On my shop I put the plastic down then the foam and lines and poured over that remember that if you are adding reenforcement metal it can not be used as a grounding method if you have a eps or vapor barrier under the slab. I left a strip along the out side edge +20’ of rebar and the inspector was ok with that for a ufer grounding electrode.